# how to show modal window in controller's action?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

So I've got controller PagesController with actions index and full_search. Action index is for home page. On home page I've got the button 'search' and text_field. If user types sometiong in text_field and clicks on button 'search' he/she goes to action full_search. In this action I try to find something by user's query. if I don't find anything I should just show a modal window with 'no results' otherwise redirect to another page

```
def full_search
  ...do search...
  if search_result.empty?
    show modal window with text 'no results'
  else
    redirect to another page
  end
end
```

How can I show modal window(like function alert in js)? I think I have to use javascript..but where???

if search_result is empty I don't need to render any view...I just need to stay at the same page and show modal window

Comment: Do you have the modal on your page? Not the content, only the structure. Like `<div class="modal...`

Comment: No I don't have it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Step 1.**

In your rendered view, have a div with id "my_modal_content" where will insert the modal's content and show the modal.

**Step 2.**

Render a js.erb file which will append the modal to our page

```
#your rails controller method
def my_method
  if something == true
    respond_to do |format|

      format.js { render :partial => 'somewhere/somefile.js.erb' }
      #I'm assuming its js request
    end
  else
    redirect to another page
  end
end
```

**Step 4.**

Write your js.erb file like this, which appends modal and then shows it.

```
#_somefile.js.erb file

$("#my_modal_content").html("<%= escape_javascript(render 'somewhere/my_modal') %>");
$("#myModal").modal('show');
```

**Step 3.**

Modal partial file **`_my_modal.html.erb`** placed within `views/somewhere/` with you modal content ready.

```
<div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" id="myModal" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    ...<!-- all your content insdie -->
  </div>
</div>
```

> Update

If you want to show an alert, its pretty straight forward. You just render js

```
if search_result.empty?
  message = "No result found. Try something else!"
  respond_to do |format| 
    format.js { render js: "alert(#{message});" }
  end
else
  redirect to another page
end
```

Comment: I should look at my question. I've made editing. Thanks anyway)

Comment: Does your search happen asynchronously?

Comment: Are you sure you want to show a modal, or just a javascript `alert`?

Comment: No..(I'm using elasticsearch)

Comment: `alert` will be fine.

Comment: I got this error `ActionController::UnknownFormat` on line respond_to do |format|

Comment: That's because your request is not asynchronous. Use `remote: true` in your form. Example:  `<%= form_tag("your_path", method: 'get', remote: true ) do %>`

Comment: We're getting the request as `html`. But out respond_to block only responds to `js` requests. Its a nice thing to have search without refreshing the page, don't you think?

Comment: if I set remote: true in form then nothing is going on when press the button...alert and redirect aren't working.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114685/discussion-between-kumar-and--).

Answer (score 1):

You can save a variable with true or false in your controller:
`@var = true`

And then in a view use javascript:

```
if (<%= @var%> == true) {
  alert("some text");
}
```

Comment: if the variable is true I don't need to render any view...I need to stay at the same page and just show modal window

Comment: Then save a variable in a controller method for the current view page, not a separate action.