# Rails4 after upload completion by input and then how to trigger bootstrap modal?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bootstrap-modal

My Gemfile:

```
gem 'rails', '4.2.8'
gem 'carrierwave', '~> 1.2', '>= 1.2.2'
gem 'mini_magick', '~> 4.8'
gem 'Jcrop', '~> 0.1.0'
```

Now I want to use `form_for` upload the user picture, my `show.html.erb`:

```
    <%= form_for @user, :html => {:multipart => true} do |f| %>
  <div class="row " id="user_avatar_crop">
    <!-- Choose Image -->
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <%= f.file_field :picture, id: :user_avatar, onchange: 'this.form.submit()'%>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>

<!-- Modal -->
<div id="uploadModalContent">

</div>

<!-- Show user picture -->
<% if @user.picture? %>
  <%= image_tag @user.picture.url(:thumb), :alt => @user.name+"_avatar" %>
  <% else %>
  <%= image_tag @user.picture.url(:thumb),:alt => @user.name+"_default" %>
  <% end %>
```

My `user_controller.rb` :

```
def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    if @user.update_attributes(user_params)
      if params[:user][:picture].present?
        respond_to do |format|
          format.html do
            flash[:warning] = "Template missing"
            redirect_to @user
          end
          format.js { render template: 'users/update.js.erb'}
        end
      else
        redirect_to @user
        flash[:success] = "Success update"
      end
    else
      render :edit
    end
  end
```

My `update.js.erb`:

```
$('#uploadModalContent').html("<%= j render "users/modal"%>");
$('#upload-modal').modal('show');
```

My `_modal.html.erb`:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="upload-modal" aria-labelledby="modalLabel" role="dialog" tabindex="-1">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Crop Image</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="col-md-8">
          <%= image_tag @user.picture_url(:large), id: "cropImage" %>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <h4>Preview</h4>
          <div style="width:100px; height:100px; overflow:hidden;">
            <%= image_tag @user.picture.url(:large), :id => "user_preview" %>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <%= form_for @user do |f| %>
          <% %w[x y w h].each do |attribute| %>
            <%= f.hidden_field "crop_#{attribute}" %>
          <% end %>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          <%= f.submit "crop" %>
        <% end %>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now I need after upload picture, the `_modal.html.erb` can display. But it seems that `format.js { render template: 'users/update.js.erb'}` in `user_controller.rb` cann't work. This is for why?

And what should I  do in `user_controller.rb` that after `input` complete `onchange: 'this.form.submit()'` it can render to the modal window? Thanks so much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I found another way to upload images in rails. I arrived at the conclusio that is the best method I know so far. You have to use [carrierwave](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave) gem. I will put now the code needed in order to use it. Anyway if you can check the github repo or this [post](https://rubyplus.com/articles/4961-File-Upload-using-Carrierwave-in-Rails-5-1).

Ok so lets go. You will have first to install the gem globally, but even locally in your project.

```
$ gem install carrierwave
```

In Rails, add it to your Gemfile:

```
gem 'carrierwave', '~> 1.0'
```

Now restart the server to apply the changes.

Start off by generating an uploader:

```
rails generate uploader Photos
```

this should give you a file in:

```
# app/uploaders/photos_uploader.rb
class PhotosUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  storage :file
  # will save photos in /app/public/uploads
  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end
end
```

Create Photos migration

```
class CreatePhotos < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :photos do |t|
      t.string :name, :null => false
      t.binary :data, :null => false
      t.string :filename
      t.string :mime_type

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

And model

```
require 'carrierwave/orm/activerecord'
class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
  mount_uploader :data, PhotosUploader
end
```

Then controller

```
class PhotosController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @photos = Photo.all
  end
  def show
    @photo = Photo.find(params[:id])
  end
  def new
    @photo = Photo.new
  end
  def create
    # build a photo and pass it into a block to set other attributes
    @photo = Photo.new(photo_params)
    # normal save
    if @photo.save
      redirect_to(@photo, :notice => 'Photo was successfully created.')
    else
      render :action => "new"
    end
  end
  private
    def photo_params
      params.require(:photo).permit!
    end
end
```

The form upload:

```
<!-- new.html.erb -->
<%= form_for(@photo, :html => {:multipart => true}) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :data %>
    <%= f.file_field :data %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Upload" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

And you load the file in a view like this.

```
<!-- show.html.erb -->
<h3>Photo: <b><%= @photo.name %></b></h3>
<%= image_tag @photo.data.url %>
```

you could also trigger a modal after image upload like this:

```
# app/assets/javascripts/photos.coffee
$ ->
  alert('Photo Uploaded - You can launch modal here')
```

All right that's all. Let me know how is going!

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer, I had try as your codes, but there is some problem. 1、`ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken`   , I had solved by add `config.action_controller.allow_forgery_protection = false ` to  `config\environments\development.rb `  。2、 And then it show another error,  `emplate is missing`  : `Missing template users/update...`，how could to repair this problem?  Thanks again.

Comment: Yes ,@neboduus ,I had the `update.js.erb` in `views/users`.

Comment: Oh, it shows the error : ` ActionController::UnknownFormat in UsersController#update`, I had change your codes at `@template_missing? ` to `@template_missing`,for with your code `@template_missing?` , my rubyMine shows the error : `Expected: expression`. Does this matter? @neboduus

Comment: The entire error is `Missing template users/update, application/update with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :arb, :coffee, :jbuilder]}. Searched in: * "/Users/hs/Desktop/uask/app/views" * "/Users/hs/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/devise-4.4.3/app/views" * "/Users/hs/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/activeadmin-1.3.0/app/views" * "/Users/hs/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/kaminari-core-1.1.1/app/views"`

Comment: But, @neboduus , I had found that if I do as this questions : `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37819575/how-to-show-modal-window-in-controllers-action` the second answer by Zelenka. If as your codes set `@template_missing`, and then I in my `show.html.erb` use js to call this variable val, and judge the value is true, at last , I can use `$("#upload").modal("show")`, this thinking can it be realized?

Comment: O.O, I use rails4.2.8, and I had added the remote: true. But it seems also the template missing error...

Comment: Ok, thank so much @neboduus. I had beset in this questions for many days . I am really really very appreciate to you。Have a good night.

Comment: Hi, @neboduus  I want to upload user picture.And after upload image with carrierwave , then trigger the modal to crop this image.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171366/discussion-between-sylor-huang-and-neboduus).