# Convert Formdata to jpeg file in Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I am working with a React front end and a Rails API, and need to know how to convert formdata, which is created in the front end with an image file appended, to a jpeg file inside a Rails controller.

So far I have been able to route the formdata to a controller and the formdata looks like so as show in my console:

```
{\"file\"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x00007f9e3227fb28 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/var/folders/7j/pqx3w4t571s4hrmdwcq3v6tm0000gn/T/RackMultipart20180519-97088-172hrqu.jpeg>, @original_filename=\"big_facade.jpeg\", @content_type=\"image/jpeg\", @headers=\"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\\\"file\\\"; filename=\\\"big_facade.jpeg\\\"\\r\\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\\r\\n\">, \"format\"=>:json, \"controller\"=>\"api/v1/images/images\", \"action\"=>\"upload\"}
```

Based on my research, this is possible but the available literature only goes as far as to say it is possible without describing how.

Can someone point me to the right direction or let me know the code?

I am using the Paperclip gem in Rails.

Comment: I will suggest to use a gem that handles file uploads on the front-end called carrierwave. You can check my answer at that post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50411985/rails4-after-upload-completion-by-input-and-then-how-to-trigger-bootstrap-modal/50414662#50414662 and check the gem git hub repo here  https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I have used Carrierwave before in a Rails front and backend app but I'm developing a Rails API only app and I'm not sure I need Carrierwave.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  def create_file
    unless params[:file].blank?
      uploaded_io = params[:file]
      path = Rails.root.join("public/system/temp_files/images", uploaded_io.original_filename)
      File.open(path, 'wb') do |file|
        file.write(uploaded_io.read)
      end
      if ExampleModel.create(image: Rails.root.join('public', path.to_s.split('/public/')[1]).open))
        File.delete(path)
      end
    end
  end
```

Explanation: -

1- First you must need to create physical file to save it in your db, so here i have created a temporary file in project's public directory.

2- Just write this file using temporary file path to your database. and after that delete this temporary physical file. Assuming that model name is `ExampleModel` and there has one field paperclip's field `image`

Comment: Thank for the response. I'm getting the error NoMethodError (undefined method `original_filename' for #<ActionController::Parameters:0x00007f9e32d93fa0>):

Comment: @bigmugcup seem you are missing something, as i can see that you have alredy `@original_filename=\"big_facade.jpeg\",` in params.
please check the above code. carefully, i have tested it before write answer. just check what are you getting in `param[:file]` .

Comment: To get rid of the 'original_filename' error, I just assigned a name in its place. Now the image is created in system directory, but now I get an error: NoMethodError (undefined method `read' for #<ActionController::Parameters:0x00007f9e35328f18>):

Comment: @bigmugcup can you paste the `params[:file]` what are you getting here?

Comment: Okay, I got an image. Sorry, I had the params wrong. Thank you so much!

Comment: @bigmugcup yea.  thanks a lot. i need one favour. i too want to learn react with rails :D. please provide me some react tut with rails or if its possible may i ask you email?

Comment: sure I would be happy to, but there is a great teacher on Udemy, Stephen Grider. You need to take his course, both Reactjs and React Native. Very inexpensive and great resource. With your coding skills you'll pick it up quickly! https://www.udemy.com/react-redux/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171378/discussion-between-bigmugcup-and-gabbar).